# The total probability as sums of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have 2 events $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ partition the probability space. Let the event I'm interested in be denoted by $X$. $C_1$ and $C_2$ and their complements (denoted as $C_1'$ and $C_2'$) are conditionally independent given $X$. The probability of $X$ is given by,

$$P(X)=P(X,C_1,C_2)+P(X,C_1',C_2)+P(X,C_1,C_2')+P(X,C_1',C_2')$$
This, in turn, is (I think) given by,
$$P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2|X)+P(X|C_1')P(C_1')P(C_2|X)+P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2'|X)+P(X|C_1')P(C_1')P(C_2'|X)$$
Have I done this correctly? I'll accept your answer if you can say yes or no, and refer to the relevant rules I've invoked/ failed to invoke.

Comment: Are you denoting complements with $´$?

Comment: Yes I am! Will clarify this.

Comment: Something is fishy, if $E$ is _any_ event, then any other no null event $F$ will be such that either $E \cap F$ or else $E' \cap F$ is not null. So, $C_1, C_2, C_1'$ and $C_2'$ cannot be a partition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: You can't have two events such that these two and their complements form a partition of the space. That is impossible.

Comment: The partition is formed by the pairwise intersections of the two events or their complements (excluding the empty intersections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the partition you require is $\{C_1\cap C_2, C_1\cap C_2', C_1'\cap C_2,C_1'\cap C_2'\}$, the pairwise intersections of the two events or their complements (excluding the empty intersections; assuming all four shown are non-empty).

Secondly, take more care when expanding conditionals; let's do it one step at a time.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X) &= \mathsf P(X,C_1,C_2)+\mathsf P(X,C_1,C_2')+\mathsf P(X,C_1',C_2)+\mathsf P(X,C_1',C_2')\\[2ex] &= {\mathsf P(C_1, C_2)\mathsf P(X\mid C_1,C_2)+ \mathsf P(C_1,C_2')\mathsf P(X\mid C_1,C_2')+\mathsf P(C_1',C_2)\mathsf P(X\mid C_1',C_2)+\mathsf P(C_1',C_2'\mid C_1')\mathsf P(X\mid C_1',C_2')}\\[2ex] &= {\mathsf P(C_1)\mathsf P(C_2\mid C_1)\mathsf P(X\mid C_1,C_2)+ \mathsf P(C_1)\mathsf P(C_2'\mid C_1)\mathsf P(X\mid C_1,C_2')+\mathsf P(C_1')\mathsf P(C_2\mid C_1')\mathsf P(X\mid C_1',C_2)+\mathsf P(C_1')\mathsf P(C_2'\mid C_1')\mathsf P(X\mid C_1',C_2')}\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks Graham. Could you take a look at my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008070/using-the-product-rule-be-to-express-the-total-probability-as-the-sum-of-conditi), where I elaborate on how I got my expression.