# Total probability as the sum of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have 2 events $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that $C_1$, $C_2$, and their complements ($C_1'$ and $C_2'$) partition the probability space. Let the event I'm interested in be denoted by $X$. $C_1$ and $C_2$ and their complements are conditionally independent given $X$. The probability of $X$ is given by,

$$P(X)=P(X,C_1,C_2)+P(X,C_1',C_2)+P(X,C_1,C_2')+P(X,C_1',C_2')$$
Using the product rule, this can be expressed as follow,
$$P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2|X,C_1)+P(X|C_1')P(C_1')P(C_2|X,C_1')+P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2'|X,C_1)+P(X|C_1)P(C_1')P(C_2'|X,C_1').$$
Secondly, using the conditional independence of $C_1$ and $C_2$ (and their complements) given $X$, this is,
$$P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2|X)+P(X|C_1')P(C_1')P(C_2|X)+P(X|C_1)P(C_1)P(C_2'|X)+P(X|C_1')P(C_1')P(C_2'|X)$$
Have I done this correctly? I'll accept your answer if you can say yes or no, and refer to the relevant rules I've invoked or failed to invoke.

Comment: "$C_1,C_2,C_1', \text{ and }C_2'$ partition the probability space..." Are thry disjoint? Or $C_j'=C_j^c$?

Comment: Yes, they are complements.

Comment: @d.k.o. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you do have that conditional independence, then that will be okay.

---

PS: It is the *non-empty pairwise intersections of the sets and their complements* that partition the  space.